# Cashier game- Matching an updated variable with static variables in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am attempting to create cash register simulation game and am running into a problem with a conditional statement that I am using to check whether the correct change is being provided to the customer and if a button is being pressed or not. In this game, the user can see the amount of the sale as well as the amount the customer pays. With this information they have to click on the cash drawer slots which will increase a variable called changeCount by the value of the monetary unit they have selected.

I am using an if statement to take them to the next frame if the changeCount = payment-sale and the confirm button has been pressed. To check for the button I am using a boolean to see if it is being pressed or not. For some reason, it is not registering the updated value of the changeCount for the if statement to work. Does anyone know why this would be? If I trace the value with trace(changeCount); it will return the value I want. 
The source code is pasted below:

```
package 
   {


public class CashierMain extends MovieClip
{
    private var confirmBtn:ConfirmButton;
    private var pennyBtn:PennyButton;
    private var dimeBtn:DimeButton;
    private var nickelBtn:NickelButton;
    private var quarterBtn:QuarterButton;
    private var oneBtn:OneButton;
    private var fiveBtn:FiveButton;
    private var tenBtn:TenButton;
    private var twentyBtn:TwentyButton;
    private var changeCount:Number;
    private var payment:int;
    private var sale:Number;
    private var clicked:Boolean;
    private var total:Number;

    public function startCashierMain()
    {
        //instantiating change count
        changeCount = 0;
        clicked = false;
        sale = Math.random() * 50;
        payment = Math.random() * 20 + sale;
        total = payment - sale;
        showPayment();
        showChangeCount();
        showSale();
        showTotal();
        //creating visuals
        confirmBtn = new ConfirmButton();
        confirmBtn.x = 450;
        confirmBtn.y = 85;
        addChild(confirmBtn);
        pennyBtn = new PennyButton();
        pennyBtn.x = 100;
        pennyBtn.y = 50;
        addChild(pennyBtn);
        nickelBtn = new NickelButton();
        nickelBtn.x = 175;
        nickelBtn.y = 50;
        addChild(nickelBtn);
        dimeBtn = new DimeButton();
        dimeBtn.x = 250;
        dimeBtn.y = 50;
        addChild(dimeBtn);
        quarterBtn = new QuarterButton();
        quarterBtn.x = 315;
        quarterBtn.y = 50;
        addChild(quarterBtn);
        oneBtn = new OneButton();
        oneBtn.x = 75;
        oneBtn.y = 200;
        addChild(oneBtn);
        fiveBtn = new FiveButton();
        fiveBtn.x = 200;
        fiveBtn.y = 200;
        addChild(fiveBtn);
        tenBtn = new TenButton();
        tenBtn.x = 325;
        tenBtn.y = 200;
        addChild(tenBtn);
        twentyBtn = new TwentyButton();
        twentyBtn.x = 450;
        twentyBtn.y = 200;
        addChild(twentyBtn);

        //Listeners
        pennyBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickPenny);
        nickelBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickNickel);
        dimeBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickDime);
        quarterBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickQuarter);
        oneBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickOne);
        fiveBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickFive);
        tenBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickTen);
        twentyBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickTwenty);
        confirmBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickConfirm);





    }


    public function clickPenny(event:MouseEvent)
    {
        changeCount +=  .01;
        showChangeCount();
    }
    public function clickNickel(event:MouseEvent)
    {
        changeCount +=  .05;
        showChangeCount();
    }
    public function clickDime(event:MouseEvent)
    {
        changeCount +=  .10;
        showChangeCount();
    }
    public function clickQuarter(event:MouseEvent)
    {
        changeCount +=  .25;
        showChangeCount();
    }
    public function clickOne(event:MouseEvent)
    {
        changeCount +=  1;
        showChangeCount();

    }
    public function clickFive(event:MouseEvent)
    {
        changeCount +=  5;
        showChangeCount();
    }
    public function clickTen(event:MouseEvent)
    {
        changeCount +=  10;
        showChangeCount();
    }
    public function clickTwenty(event:MouseEvent)
    {
        changeCount +=  20;
        showChangeCount();
    }

    public function showChangeCount()
    {
        showChange.text = String("Change Tendered $ " + changeCount.toFixed(2));


    }
    public function showPayment()
    {
        paid.text = String("Amount Paid $ " + payment);

    }
    public function showSale()
    {
        totalSale.text = String("Cost of Sale " + sale.toFixed(2));

    }
    public function showTotal()
    {
        totaled.text = String("total $ " + total.toFixed(2));

    }
    public function clickConfirm(event:MouseEvent)
    {
        if (total == changeCount && clicked == false)
        {
            gotoAndPlay("next");
        }
    }






}
```

}

I am fairly new to this website, so if my question seems to vague or you don't understand what I am asking, feel free to have me clarify anything. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Where do you trace the changeCount? In clickConfirm?
And have you tried trace( total, changeCount, clicked ) in clickConfirm? What does it output?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm not sure why you need the `clicked` variable anyways. You have the event listener to see whether the button was clicked or not.

You get the mismatch, because the `total` and `changeCount` are actually different. Since `Math.random()` generates values between 0 and 1. You get variables for both your `sale` and `payment` variables to have many numbers after the fraction number (like 20.23515542354624 etc). Since You don't round the numbers, only show them as rounded in your GUI (`toFraction(2)` doesn't round the numbers it just returns a string of the rounded representation) you end up comparing something like that 20.23515542354624 to 20.23, which obviously isn't equal.

Trace out all your numeric variables, You'll see what I mean if You don't get it now.

The solution is to round your `total` variable to .xx format, like this:

`total = Math.round((payment - sale) * 100) / 100;`

*I'm sorry, my technical English for mathematics knowledge is bad, I use a lot of made-up terms.*

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you for the help. I didn't think I needed that boolean variable, but when things stopped working the ways I wanted them to I decided to try to cover as many details as I could think of. Fresh eyes always prevail. Thanks again.

Comment: This solution works some of the time, but I found another bug. It seems like when I am adding a fraction of a dollar, it is having trouble with the rounding as well. For instance, when I add .01 to a changeCount of 3.01 it sometimes results in 3.01999999999. Why does it not just add a full .01 and why would it only be some of the time?

Comment: @co-Mcdan — this is completely normal and happens because of how [floating point numbers are stored in computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers). Basically, 0.01 is never that like on paper. In computers it's very close to the value but no it (something like 0.009999999999999999) - this is because of the architecture stuff. If you really want to pursue a programmers career — I strongly suggest learning the quirks of Computer Science.

Comment: @co-Mcdan — For this particular situation, I would suggest ditching using Number values completely. Switch to handling money as cents (using int variables). You won't have to worry about floating point number and other math quirks anymore. For example, the purchase is 2056 cents ($20.56) and the client gave 3000 ($30.00) cents. Then you add cents to your `changeCount` variable (adding a $1 equals to adding 100 cents). When you display the totals to the user — simply divide cents by 100, you'll get the $xx.yy format. Hope this helps. All the best.

Comment: @co-Mcdan — Oh, and I had no intent to sound offensive on the programer's career comment. I just thought, that maybe you're more into arts and you were doing this as a side project. Cheers man, glad to help!

Comment: No offense taken. It is exactly as you just said. I am typically in the role of arts, music, writing... but for this project I decided to take on programming duties.